# ORTE was unable to reliably start one or more daemons

Tags: mpi

I have installed mpi and when i run

```
mpirun --allow-run-as-root -np 1 cpi
```

then it can run correctly just like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqq5P.png)

But when i run

```
mpirun --allow-run-as-root -machinefile hosts -np 1 cpi
```

then there will be an error：

bash: orted: command not found

---

ORTE was unable to reliably start one or more daemons.
This usually is caused by:

- not finding the required libraries and/or binaries on
  one or more nodes. Please check your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  settings, or configure OMPI with --enable-orterun-prefix-by-default
- lack of authority to execute on one or more specified nodes.
  Please verify your allocation and authorities.
- the inability to write startup files into /tmp (--tmpdir/orte_tmpdir_base).
  Please check with your sys admin to determine the correct location to use.
- compilation of the orted with dynamic libraries when static are required
  (e.g., on Cray). Please check your configure cmd line and consider using
  one of the contrib/platform definitions for your system type.
- an inability to create a connection back to mpirun due to a
  lack of common network interfaces and/or no route found between
  them. Please check network connectivity (including firewalls
  and network routing requirements).

---

this is 'hosts' file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrjE7.png)

'master' is the name of this host and 'slave1' is the name of another host and i am sure that two hosts can log in via 'ssh'.

Comment: Try using the full path to mpirun instead (e.g. /opt/openmpi/bin/mpirun)

Answer (score 1):

try absolute path such as `/usr/lib64/openmpi3/bin/mpirun` instead of `mpirun`